# Is adding text to SurfaceView a best practices?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

Is it correct to add a text to `SurfaceView`? Or is it better to divide the screen into 2 layouts: one with the text and one with the `SurfaceView`? What it the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Views are all drawn on the same GUI thread which is also used for all user interaction.
So if you need to update GUI rapidly or if the rendering takes too much time and affects user experience then use SurfaceView.

Comment: hey, @Stefano Hope my answer help you. So Please Accept it. Thankyou